# Misalignment of bounding boxes with `psfrag`

Tags: horizontal-alignment, psfrag, bounding-box

**My problem**

The left side of the replacement text written by `psfrag` is horizontally shifted with respect to that of the tag I inserted in my PostScript file, although I use "l" (left) for both the `posn` and `psposn` parameters. What is the reason for this and how to solve this problem? I am interested in a general solution, not one specific to the example below.

**Details**

This problem is illustrated with the files "MWE_tagged.eps" and "MWE_substit.tex" provided hereafter.

With the `show` PostScript command, I have inserted two tags, ".TAG1" and "_TAG2", at the same coordinates in file "MWE_tagged.eps" (first file below). Since I use a monospaced font and `show` sets the baseline and the left side of the bounding box of these tags at the same position, the two "TAG" strings are indiscernible.

[image: "MWE_tagged.eps" (converted to png format)]

*File "MWE_tagged.eps" (converted to `png` format).*

Then, with the `psfrag` package, I replace in LaTeX file "MWE_substit.tex" (second file below) the tag ".TAG1" by "01" and "_TAG2" by "02". The commands I use are the following:

`\psfrag{.TAG1}[Bl][Bl][1][0]{01}`;

`\psfrag{_TAG2}[Bl][Bl][1][0]{02}`.

Given the values of the `psposn` and `posn` parameters, I would expect that the left side of "01" and "02" coincide. However, for some reason, "01" is shifted to the right with respect to "02".

[image: "MWE_substit.ps" (converted to png format)]

*File "MWE_substit.ps" (converted to `png` format).*

What is the reason for this? Is this due to the sidebearing inserted on the left (and right) side of the bounding box by PostScript? How to correct for this? My goal is to have the left side of the bounding box of "01" and "02" aligned along the red vertical line.

---

**File "MWE_tagged.eps"**

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 290 373 322 419
%%HiResBoundingBox: 290.000000 373.000000 322.000000 418.500000
%%For: fioc
%%Title: PGPLOT PostScript plot
%%Creator: PGPLOT [PSDRIV 6.6]
%%CreationDate:  6-Oct-2022 11:01
%%LanguageLevel: 1
%%EndComments
% EPSF created by ps2eps 1.68
%%BeginProlog
save
countdictstack
mark
newpath
/showpage {} def
/setpagedevice {pop} def
%%EndProlog
%%Page 1 1
%%BeginProlog
/L {moveto rlineto currentpoint stroke moveto} bind def
/C {rlineto currentpoint stroke moveto} bind def
/D {moveto 0 0 rlineto currentpoint stroke moveto} bind def
/LW {5 mul setlinewidth} bind def
/BP {newpath moveto} bind def
/LP /rlineto load def
/EP {rlineto closepath eofill} bind def
/MB {gsave translate MFAC dup scale 1 setlinewidth 2 setlinecap 0 setlinejoin newpath} bind def
/ME /grestore load def
/CC {0 360 arc stroke} bind def
/FC {0 360 arc fill} bind def
/G {1024 div setgray} bind def
/K {3 -1 roll 1024 div 3 -1 roll 1024 div 3 -1 roll 1024 div setrgbcolor} bind def
% Uncomment next line to convert color to grey shades
%/K {3 -1 roll 3413 div 3 -1 roll 1739 div 3 -1 roll 9309 div add add setgray} bind def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
/#copies 1 def
%%EndSetup
 
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
/PGPLOT save def
0.072 0.072 scale
8149 250 translate 90 rotate
1 setlinejoin 1 setlinecap 1 LW 1
%%EndPageSetup
%%PageBoundingBox: (atend)
1024 0 0 K 1 LW 625 0 4937 3900 L
0 437 5250 3681 L
0 0 0 K
/Courier findfont
100 scalefont
setfont
5250 3900 moveto
(.TAG1) show
5250 3900 moveto
(_TAG2) show
PGPLOT restore showpage
%%PageTrailer
%%PageBoundingBox: 289 373 323 419
 
%%Trailer
%%DocumentFonts: 
%%Pages: 1
%%Trailer
cleartomark
countdictstack
exch sub { end } repeat
restore
%%EOF
```

---

**File "MWE_substit.tex"**

Compile with `latex MWE_substit` and `dvips MWE_substit.dvi -o MWE_substit.ps`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{courier}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\psfrag{.TAG1}[Bl][Bl][1][0]{01}%
\psfrag{_TAG2}[Bl][Bl][1][0]{02}%
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[angle=-90,width=\linewidth]{MWE_tagged.eps}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like the `01` replacement is inserted at the actual position of `.` in the EPS output, not at the 5250 coordinate specified in the `moveto`.

Comment: Indeed the psfrag manual mentions (emphasis mine) "PostScript has five commands to display text—show, ashow, kshow, widthshow, and awidthshow— [...] PSfrag actually intercepts these commands and checks them for the tags to replace. When the string matches a known tag, PSfrag **figures out where the tag would have been displayed**, and inserts its replacement there". Indeed, when checking the source, a large part of `psfrag.pro` seems to be devoted to figuring out the exact target position (although I have to admit that I have difficulty understanding the postscript code fully).

Comment: Anyway, the manual also mentions "When adding a piece of text (a tag) in a figure for PSfrag to replace, use a single word, containing only unaccented letters and numbers". Extending this advice a simple solution would be to indeed not use `.` and `_`, or if you want to use them to make sure that the first character is always the same.

Comment: I first noticed the problem with tag `zero`, which I replaced with "0", and I found that this "0" was not properly aligned. I used tags starting with `.` and `_` in the example because it enhances the problem. Actually, the alignment is almost correct when starting with `_` because this character takes almost all the width in a monospaced font, so I could indeed start all my tags with an underscore.

Comment: Regarding your first two comments, the inner working of `psfrag` is way beyond my competences. Would the authors of the package, especially David Carlisle if he is around, have any clue?

Comment: David can most likely explain (in more detail and with more accuracy than me) what is going on indeed, you can go to the [site chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=tex.stackexchange.com) and ask him, he is usually around. I am not sure though whether he can actually provide a change in this functionality, from what I have seen this would require modifying the core of the package code.